# Split string in Windows batch file over multiple lines

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want to invoke an elevated Powershell to execute a script and pass a bunch of parameters. I would like to have every parameter in the .bat file on its own line. Usually I can use the carat ^ to span commands over several lines in .bat files, just like using a grave accent ` in Powershell scripts. But both don't work in this situation:

As a one-liner it works:

```
Powershell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process Powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %~dp0HelloWorld.ps1 -parameter1 Long -parameter2 list -parameter3 of -parameter4 parameters' }"
```

Trying to split it up into multiple lines using a caret ^ doesn't work:

```
Powershell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process Powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %~dp0HelloWorld.ps1 ^
-parameter1 Long ^
-parameter2 list ^
-parameter3 of ^
-parameter4 parameters ^
'}"
```

Here is an example `HelloWorld.ps1` to test with, (has to be in the same directory as the batch file):

```
param (
    $parameter1="",
    $parameter2="",
    $parameter3="",
    $parameter4=""
)

write-host "$parameter1 $parameter2 $parameter3 $parameter4"

Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue...';
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
```

Comment: You do not need to use a GRAVE ACCENT (backtick) for a single statement. cmd.exe will concatenate the lines with the CARET.

Comment: @lit as I wrote I am aware that I can use a GRAVE ACCENT in a Powershell script in order to concatenate lines, like I do in a .bat file with a CARET. In my question and example I am not using grave accents at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to handle the issue in your example case above, is to use doublequotes, `"` instead of single, `'`. However to prevent `cmd.exe` from failing to parse the command, you'll need to escape those nested doublequotes, using backslashes, i.e. `\"`.

Example:

```batch-file
@Powershell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process Powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList \" ^
 -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned ^
 -File `\"%~dp0HelloWorld.ps1`\" ^
 -parameter1 Long ^
 -parameter2 list ^
 -parameter3 of ^
 -parameter4 parameters ^
\"}"
```

I have specifically changed the `ExecutionPolicy` from `Bypass`, *(which I wouldn't ever recommend using, even moreso when running elevated)*, to `RemoteSigned`, please do not change it back. Also for added safety, I have quoted your `.ps1` file path, which could contain spaces. The backslashes escape the doublequotes for the `cmd.exe` parser, *(as already mentioned)*, and then backticks escape the remaining nested doublequotes for the `powershell.exe` parser.